# How to scrape javascript in html using bs4 when unrendered. (No selenium)

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a product page for its variants/ids but don't know how to in javascript in html with bs4.

I am clueless and would like to know the fastest code that can be able to extract this data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

session = requests.session()


def get_ava_sizes():
    global session
    endpoint = 'https://fasttimes.com.au/nike-sb-zoom-blazer-mid-iso-white-black-safety-orange-80817'
    response = session.get(endpoint)

    soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
   #print(response.text)

    select =  soup.find('script', {'type':'text/javascript'})
    sizes = select.find_all('id')

    ava_sizes = []
    for size in sizes:
        size_id = size['']

    return ava_sizes

print(get_ava_sizes())
```

Comment: Sample ids would look like?

Comment: Could you please include your desired output

Comment: Hi Tony,

Please share your desired output. You have linked to one product, are you after several? Should the starting page be the category page?

Comment: @QHarr All product pages have this format and I would like to scrape this part https://pastebin.com/f6xb6YR3 of the html to get the list of ids 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 view-source:https://fasttimes.com.au/nike-sb-zoom-blazer-mid-iso-white-black-safety-orange-80817

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follows? I assume to exclude "label":"Size" - the first id.

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://fasttimes.com.au/nike-sb-zoom-blazer-mid-iso-white-black-safety-orange-80817')
p = re.compile(r'"id":"(\d+)",', re.DOTALL)
ids = p.findall(r.text)[1:]
print(ids)
```

Comment: `import requests`
`import re`
`p_url = input('Fasttimes Product URL: ')`
`r = requests.get(p_url)`
`def get_sizes():`
`p = re.compile(r'"id":"(\d+)",', re.DOTALL) `
`    ids = [] `
`    ids = p.findall(r.text)[1:] `
`    return ids`
`print(get_sizes()) `

Comment: Could I also ask what would be the code if I was finding for https://pastebin.com/q7MBQP8s , could you find the link within in it using bs4 please. view-source:https://fasttimes.com.au/nike-sb-zoom-blazer-mid-iso-white-black-safety-orange-80817

Comment: What link are you after?

Comment: https://fasttimes.com.au/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9mYXN0dGltZXMuY29tLmF1L25pa2Utc2Item9vbS1ibGF6ZXItbWlkLWlzby13aGl0ZS1ibGFjay1zYWZldHktb3JhbmdlLTgwODE3P19fX1NJRD1V/product/80817/form_key/wsZCb9SwANcIDbFd/

Comment: Sorry. I thought that was the link to use :-)

Comment: All good, just wanted to know how I use bs4 to find it in the source code if that possible. Can't work out the exact soup.find code.

Comment: soup.select_one('#product_addtocart_form')['action']

Comment: Thanks again for your help!